# Synchronous GET request

Tags: node.js, get

I have the following script:

```
var request = require("request");
var slogans = request.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/queatech/slogans/master/slogans.txt", function(err, res, body){
    if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
        return body.split("\n").splice(-1);
    }
});
console.log(slogans);
```

I want the output of the script to be

> ['The Ultimate Q&A Site', 'The Free Q&A Site', 'The Idea Q&A Site']

But instead I'm getting the long JSON GET query. Is there a way to set the variable `slogans` to the GET request of https://raw.githubusercontent.com/queatech/slogans/master/slogans.txt?
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the request library source code [1], `request.get` will return a `Request` object. What you actually need is the response.

You have passed a function to your `request.get` call, it's called a callback and this function receives arguments `err`, `res`, and `body`. `res` stands for response, inspect it to find what you're looking for. Tipically, `body` contains the data you're requesting.

You can only access these variables (`err`, `res`, and `body`) inside the scope of the the callback function and the body of the callback function will only execute at a time when the response to your request arrives.

Whatever code you write after `request.get` will be executed "in parallel", meaning that it won't wait for your response to arrive.

[1] https://github.com/request/request/blob/master/index.js

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't solve my question. I'm wondering, how can I set the `slogans` variable to the value of [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/queatech/slogans/master/slogans.txt) page split by the character "\n" in a GET request?

Comment: If you really want to keep your code lines in this shape you can look into async await.